# Saving dynamic formset with more than one form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, formset

I've built dynamic forms using django formsets and javascript, but unfortunately on submitting the form only the first form is submitted. I'd like all dynamically added forms to be submitted also. Any help would be appreciated.
Views:

```
def routestepinfo(request):
    class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                for form in self.forms:
                    form.empty_permitted = False    
    RouteStepFormSet = formset_factory(RouteStepForm, formset=RequiredFormSet, extra=1, can_order=False, can_delete=True)   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = RouteStepFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset.forms:
                form.save()
                print 'apple'
                return redirect("/buildpage/")
    else: 
        formset = RouteStepFormSet()
    return render(request, "buildpage/routestepinfo.html", {'formset' :formset})
```

HTML

```
<form id= "myForm" method = 'POST' action="{% url 'buildpage:routestepinfo' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                  {{ formset.management_form }}
<div id="form_set">    
                  {% for form in formset %}  
                  <table class='no_error'>
                  <tbody>.
                  {{form.as_table}}
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
                  {% endfor %}
</div>
<p><input type = "button" value = "Add another step" id = "add_more" ></p>
<div id="empty_form" style="display:none">
    <table class='no_error'>
        {{ formset.empty_form.as_table }}
    </table>
</div>
                 <div id="forms"></div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
              <input type = "submit" name = "Submit Steps">
                  </form>
```

JS Clone:

```
<script>
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't appear to be giving each dynamic form a unique name attribute.  eg. any INPUT's etc inside your `formset.empty_form.as_table` will need there name attribute modifying.  Unless of course your have them prefixed with `__prefix__`.  If you look at the forms in chrome debugger, are all you field's getting unique name attributes.

Comment: Hi Keith, according to the docs providing a BaseFormSet gives an automatic prefix of __prefix__, unless I've misunderstood. ``BaseFormSet`` provides an additional attribute ``empty_form`` which returns
a form instance with a prefix of ``__prefix__`` for easier use in dynamic
forms with JavaScript.

Comment: So I guess the follow up question is, is there a method of creating unique ID's with each additional form through javascript?

Comment: I think this line -> `$('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));`  is your problem, your not actually replacing anything..

Comment: `var h = $('#form_set').find('#empty_form').html();`   `$('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html(h.replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx))`   I would also suggest, to make sure this is doing what you expect, that from say Chrome debugger have a look at the Elements tab and see what `name` attributes have been set.

Comment: I'm a bit of a javascript amateur myself, using that line has given the error Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, yeah.. Looking at your HTML, you #empty_form, is not inside your #form_set..  So it should have just been `var h = $('#empty_form').html();`

Comment: Interestingly, the cloned elements look like this <input id="id_undefined-undefined-order" min="0" name="undefined-undefined-order" type="number" value="1">

Comment: I assume form_idx is then undefined.  `var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();`  where is `#id_form-TOTAL-FORMS` getting set?

Comment: Hi Keith, so I fixed the id issue, but still only one form is saving. I don't think javascript is the fix for that, so I'm trying out different things on my views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it ! Only took a week. Here's how it worked eventually. Views are largely unmodified, just added commit=False to save the list.

```
def routestepinfo(request, slug=None):
    RouteStepFormSet = formset_factory(RouteStepForm, formset = RequiredFormSet, extra=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = RouteStepFormSet(request.POST)
        print formset
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset.forms:
                form_item = form.save(commit=False)
                print form
                form_item.save()
                messages.success(request, "Record created")
            return redirect ("/buildpage/")
    else: 
        formset = RouteStepFormSet()
    return render(request, "buildpage/routestepinfo.html",{'formset':formset})
```

Javascript was the main thing that changed, with quite a few additions and quite a bit of SO help. The prefix was the first issue, and that was fixed by using formset.empty_form and modifying it from there. Another vital part was updating the total forms, which fixed the saving issue.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add-item').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var count = $('#items-form-container').children().length;
        var tmplMarkup = $('#item-template').html();
        var compiledTmpl = tmplMarkup.replace(/__prefix__/g, count);
        $('div#items-form-container').append(compiledTmpl);

        // update form count
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').attr('value', count+1);
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#add-item-button").position().top-200
            }, 800);
    });
});
</script>
```

Finally the html. This combined some of my own stuff with a very helpful SO post(forgot the question it came from), where formset is generated as an empty form and cloned from there.:

```
        <div type="text/html" id="item-template">
          <table>
              {{ formset.empty_form.as_table }}
          </table>
          </div>
          <font face = Flexo>
          <form id= "myForm" method = 'POST' action="{% url 'buildpage:routestepinfo' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ formset.management_form }}
          <div id="items-form-container">

          {% for form in formset.forms %}

          <div id="item-{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
          <table>
          {{form.as_table}}
          <table>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
          <a href="#" id="add-item-button" class="btn btn-info add-item">Add Step</a>
        <input type = "submit" name = "Submit Steps">
          </form>
```

Hope this helps some people. Cheers